# How to merge/collapse child DOM node into parent with BeautifulSoup / lxml?

Tags: html, dom, merge, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am writing some HTML pre-processing scripts that are cleaning/tagging HTML from a web crawler, for use in a semantic/link analysis step that follows. I have filtered out undesired tags from the HTML, and simplified it to contain only visible text and `<div>` / `<a>` elements.

I now am trying to write a "collapseDOM()" function to walk through the DOM tree and perform the following actions:

(1) destroy leaf nodes without any visible text

(2) collapse any `<div>`, replacing it with its child, if it (a) directly contains no visible text AND (b) has only a single `<div>` child

So for instance if I have the following HTML as input:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
             <a href="www.foo.com">not collapsed into empty parent: only divs</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                inner div not collapsed because this contains text 
                <div>some more text ...</div>
                but the outer nested divs do get collapsed
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>This won't be collapsed into parent because </div>
        <div>there are two children ...</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

It should get transformed into this "collapsed" version:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
         <a href="www.foo.com">not collapsed into empty parent: only divs</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        inner div not collapsed because this contains text 
        <div>some more text ...</div>
        but the outer nested divs do get collapsed
    </div>


    <div>
        <div>This won't be collapsed into parent because </div>
        <div>there are two children ...</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

I have been unable to figure out how to do this. I tried writing a recursive tree-walking function using BeautifulSoup's `unwrap()` and `decompose()` methods, but this modified the DOM while iterating over it and I couldn't figure out how to get it to work ...

Is there a simple way to do what I want? I am open to solutions either in BeautifulSoup or lxml. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can start with this and adjust to your own needs:

```
def stripTagWithNoText(soup):

def remove(node):
    for index, item in enumerate(node.contents):
        if not isinstance(item, NavigableString):
            currentNodes = [text for text in item.contents if not isinstance(text, NavigableString) or (isinstance(text, NavigableString) and  len(re.sub('[\s+]', '', text)) > 0)]
            parentNodes = [text for text in item.parent.contents if not isinstance(text, NavigableString) or (isinstance(text, NavigableString) and  len(re.sub('[\s+]', '', text)) > 0)]

            if len(currentNodes) == 1 and item.name == item.parent.name:
                if len(parentNodes) > 1:
                    continue
                if item.name == currentNodes[0].name and len(currentNodes) == 1:
                    item.replaceWithChildren()
                node.unwrap()


for tag in soup.find_all():
    remove(tag)
print(soup)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
stripTagWithNoText(soup)
```

> `<html>
>      <body>
>         <div>
>            <a href="www.foo.com">not collapsed into empty parent: only divs</a>
>         </div>
>         <div>
>            inner div not collapsed because this contains text 
>            <div>some more text ...</div>
>            but the outer nested divs do get collapsed
>         </div>
>         <div>
>            <div>This won't be collapsed into parent because </div>
>            <div>there are two children ...</div>
>         </div>
>      </body>
>   </html>`

Comment: Actually, it appears to be failing for this test case (not collapsing nested divs): `<html><body><div><div><div>This is deep down in the divs</div></div></div></body></html>`